# Can't set up task to run from non admin user

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, scheduled-task, task-scheduler

I have Windows server 2008 R2. One non administrator account named for e.x. abc. abc is member of backup operators, power users and schedulers. I have allowed all permissions to C:\Windows\Tasks for schedulers. I checked, that groups backup operators and schedules are in list in local policy so these can log on as batch job. When I try to set up task I get "Task Scheduler cannot create the task. The user account is unknown, the password is incorrect, or the user account does not have permission to create this task". Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

For troubleshooting purposes you could attempt to add the account directly in the policy, instead of as a member of a group.  Also, you may want to verify the Group Policy setting  "Network access: Do not allow storage of credentials or .NET Passports for network authentication"